# Angular 7. Редирект на 404 при комбинации lazy loading модулей и обычных

Tags: angular2, angular-routing

Есть проект в котором используются и Lazy loading модули и обычные.

`AppRoutingModule`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  // Пример ленивого модуля.
  {
    path: 'catalog',
    loadChildren: 'app/modules/catalog/catalog.module#CatalogModule'
  },
  ...
  // Модуль с 404й страницей
  {
     path: '**',
     loadChildren: 'app/modules/not-found/not-found.module#NotFoundModule'
  },
  // Не ленивые модули сдесь не объявленны они объявленны на прямую в AppModule
];
```

И все было бы ничего, но модули объявленные **не** в данном файле, а объявленные как обычные модули в `AppModule` в проперти `imports`,

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    // Ленивый объевлен в AppRoutingModule
    CatalogModule, 
    // Обычный объявлен только тут и хранит свой path только внутри своего DictionaryRoutingModule
    DictionaryModule, 
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
}
```

С точки зрения `AppRoutingModule` где объявленна 404 страница с `path: '**'` никакого `DictionaryRoutingModule` нету.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dictionary',
    component: DictionariesComponent,
  },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DictionaryRoutingModule {
}
```

И `DictionaryRoutingModule`, - становятся не доступен. Так как при попытке перейти по их `url` срабатывает `path: '**'` из `AppRoutingModule` и роутер перекидывает на страницу 404. Таким образом все модули обявленные обычным не ленивым способом не доступны а вместо них отображается 404.

Самым очевидным выходом было бы объявить все модули ленивыми и тогда проблема отпадает. Но в качестве условия для этой задачи я получил требование не модифицировать обычные модули в ленивые.

Как в таких условиях можно реализоавть универсальный механизм перехвата не существующих адресов, таким образом, чтобы в списке существующих учитывались не только лениво подгружаемые модули, но и обычные?

Comment: покажи же весь код :)

Comment: @overthesanity не реально, во первых его очень много во вторых он NDA. Проблематику я вроде описал, или если не понятно то что?

Comment: @overthesanity расширил описание возможно так будет понятнее

Comment: я вряд ли соглашусь что файл роутинга под NDA :D ты ж не конфиги шаришь и секретные ключи :) вообще в таких случаях лучше всего делать репродакшн проблемы на stackblitz, ибо никто не будет пытаться репродьюсить твой код у себя локально :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы зарегестрировать `dictionary` на уровне `AppRoutingModule` и `**` его не перехватывал, нужно чтобы такой путь был именно в `AppRoutingModule`. Можно решить это редиректом на него же:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  // Так роутер знает что путь dictionary существует и ** его не перехватывает.
  {
    path: 'dictionary',
    redirectTo: 'dictionary'
  },
  {
    path: 'catalog',
    loadChildren: 'app/modules/catalog/catalog.module#CatalogModule'
  },
  {
     path: '**',
     loadChildren: 'app/modules/not-found/not-found.module#NotFoundModule'
  },
  // Не ленивые модули сдесь не объявленны они объявленны на прямую в AppModule
];
```